# Normalization method

Tags: phyloseq

I am a PhD student working on microbiome 16S rRNA sequence data. I have this code for phyloseq normalization from a previous student and wanted to ask if someone could help explain exactly what it is doing:

`ps_norm <-  transform_sample_counts(ps, function(x) x / sum(x) )`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation of `transform_sample_counts` [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/phyloseq/versions/1.16.2/topics/transform_sample_counts)

> This function transforms the sample counts of a taxa abundance matrix according to a user-provided function. The counts of each sample will be transformed individually. No sample-sample interaction/comparison is possible by this method.